# Compiler claims NuGet package missing namespace, decompiler disagrees?

Tags: c#, namespaces, nuget

I have a project (call it `Fancy.Common.Types`) containing some commonly used enums and marker types, which is `ProjectReference`'d by a lot of projects in a solution.

However, I wish to release one of these projects (call it `Fancy.Service.Client`) as a NuGet package, so I created a NuGet package of `Fancy.Common.Types`, released to our company feed.

I have thise NuGet package downloaded. Opening it with JetBrains' dotPeek decompiler, I can see it contains all the correct enum definitions and such; nothing seems to be amiss.

When I replace the `ProjectReference` to `Fancy.Common.Types` in `Fancy.Service.Client.csproj` with a `PackageReference` to the new NuGet package, I get the following error:

```
The type or namespace 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'Fancy' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Google is, predictably, proving unhelpful. I am nearing the point where I give up software development and go live as a hermit in the mountains, what on earth am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

- Cleaning the solution
- Building in a CI pipeline
- Ensuring the frameworks are the same for `Fancy.Common.Types` and `Fancy.Service.Client` (they are both net6.0.)
- Checking for spelling mistakes (there are none, I converted the project from using a project reference to a package reference of the same project, the names haven't changed.)

**ETA:** @PMF suggested that I might have `ProjectReference` dependencies in `Fancy.Service.Client` which in turn have `ProjectReference`s directly to `Fancy.Common.Types`. This does turn out to be the case, but does not seem to be the cause of the issue.

There is another project `Fancy.Messages` which has no `ProjectReference` dependencies aside from `Fancy.Common.Types` and if I change that to a `PackageReference`, the error persists there.

**ETA2:** Spent sixty legal minutes chasing down dependencies, and finally found it, it was as @PMF suggested, a dependency conflict.

Comment: Does your `Fancy.Service.Client` reference any other projects in your solution? A problem could arise if there are (indirectly) references to both the nuget and the original project.

Comment: @PMF It does reference other projects, and I just went and checked exactly what you suggested. I have a `Fancy.Messages` project that similarly uses `Fancy.Common.Types` but has no internal project references at all, and the error is apparent there as well.

Comment: Does this happen only on machines where you tested earlier builds of the package, that used the same version number?  NuGet expects packages to be globally unique and immutable, so once it extracts a package in the global packages folder, it never needs to download the same package again. But this means that package authors need to take care and use unique prerelease version numbers when testing their package before the "real version" is published. Within the same solution/repo use ProjectReference, not PackageReference, to projects that create packages that will be published.

Comment: Poking around a bit: One occassion where I saw this behavior is if the nuget couldn't be read correctly. Inside your nuget, is the dll located at `lib\net6.0\Fancy.Common.Types.dll`?

Comment: @zivkan There is currently only one version of the package available.

Comment: @PMF It was as you said, I was insufficiently dilligent in verifying the first time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the issue was that somewhere along in the deep tree of dependencies there was a `ProjectReference` to the `Fancy.Common.Types` project. Once I eliminated that, it compiled.

Just another 'gotcha' when working with dotnet packages: there is no sanity checks for conflicts like this.

A less generous individual than myself might deem this a glaring design flaw, that probably costs the average dotnet developer a hundred hours of lost productivity over their career.